What are some open problems to give interns?
Background: I'm a PhD student in Europe. Currently working on method/code development for computational chemistry. I have experience in DFT, code optimization, MD and Machine learning. But I'm not confident enough to find moderately impactful research gaps yet.
This year, I happen to be approached by a few masters students interested in computational chemistry. Are there any open problems (method-development or application oriented), which I can give them? I could turn them away due to the lack of problems I have. But then i feel that it would be nice to provide them with projects which would benefit them in getting maybe a portfolio project which they can present to potential PhD advisors. There are a few constraints that the projects should conform to, due to current scenario of the students:

The project shouldn't involve the use of HPC resources, as they don't have access to them. Hence I could rule out projects related to high throughput screening and so on.
They are really good with mathematics and programming. So projects related to method development can be an option. I'm aware of research gaps in my PhD thesis (related to MD and force fields), which can be packaged into small projects, but I wouldn't prefer to do this due to potential clashes with my advisor.
It shouldn't be something trivial like writing a regex wrapper around an existing quantum chemistry code or making an automated workflow. As i think we already have quite a lot of them (Eg. Quantum Espresso).
I can be completed at least partially within a few months (ideally 3 to 4 months).

I'm interested in websites, or resources which might give me some inspiration to formulate small projects for my interns. Google's SOC is one source I've used in the past, but it doesn't have what I need.
I'm not sure if I've framed the question well enough and it seems a bit broad, I could expand it based on the comments.

I think it would be better if you further specify which application fields and methods you are most interested in. What you currently have mentioned still seems too vague

There's lots to do to improve the package I work on, ELECTRODE (https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/157/8/084801/2841985/ELECTRODE-An-electrochemistry-package-for), but you need to choose projects that will synergize well with your PhD for best effect!
